# Using AlpineJS in conjunction with imported javascript library

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, date-fns

So I'm trying to build a basic calendar app using Tailwind/AlpineJS and want to use date-fns as my date library.  I've installed the date-fns package, and now I'm trying to get it to work within my HTML.

I've written this script at the bottom of my HTML document, targetting a `<div>` with `"x-data=calendarApp"`

```
<script type="module">
    import {startOfToday} from 'date-fns';

    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('calendarApp', () => ({

            currentMonthAndYear: format(startOfToday(), 'MMMM yyyy'),

        }))
    })

</script>
```

Thinking it might be a scope issue, I tried `window.addEventListener` as well, but the console keeps telling me that calendarApp is not defined.

Using non-module script tags with the same JavaScript works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself per documentation (go figure).

https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#registering-from-a-bundle

Imported a new javascript file (calendar.js) and added it to Alpine.Data.